# Convert canvas coordinates to coordinates of the external widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am building a plot and need to link labels that are located in a parent widget according to the Y axis value of a point, which is located in the canvas (QwtPlotCanvas).

I have tried so many approaches, only one shows some more or less reasonable numbers: plot->transform() and then mapTo() in the parent widget.

Plot.cpp

```
QPoint(plot_->transform(QwtPlot::xBottom, pointsToMap.x()), plot_->transform(QwtPlot::yLeft, pointsToMap.y()));
```

MainWidget.cpp

```
auto points = graph->getPlot()->canvas()->mapTo(this, graph->getPointsToMap());
```

I get a coordinate that corresponds to the top of my canvas.

I expect the coordinate to be on the same Y-offset in the main widget that it was in the canvas.

Comment: Okay, it looks like ```plot_->transform``` always gives the same coordinates that correspond to the top of the canvas no matter what value I pass.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to use a method `canvasMap` from `QwtPlot`.